# How to get the source code of built-in module?

Tags: python

The source code of module or function can be get from inspect .

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(moduleName.function))
```

What about if the module is a built_in module?

```
import sys
print(inspect.getsource(sys))

TypeError: <module 'sys' (built-in)> is a built-in module .
```

Where can i get it then ?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: @Sneftel Put a bit of explaining text around it, and it’s the correct answer to this question.

Comment: @Sneftel Note that this is a semi-official mirror (admittedly with a nicer UI), the authoritative source is a Mercurial repository at http://hg.python.org/cpython/

Comment: @delnan Yeah, but the Hg web interface is truly execrable compared to Github's. Worth the semi-officiality. ;-)

Comment: @Sneftel When I have to look up more than one thing in a week, I clone the repository and look through it locally anyway (`ack-grep`, `find`, and the like beat any web interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys` module is one of the very few ones which are not implemented in Python itself, but in native code instead. The C source is located in [`/Python/sysmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Python/sysmodule.c).

Most of the other modules are directly implemented in Python. You can find the source for those in your `lib` directory of your Python installation, or also [in the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib).